# how to add a trial license to intellij idea on linux?

Tags: intellij-idea, license-key

I unpacked `ideaIU-2019.2.4-jbr8.tar.gz` and I tried to execute via x11 server on wsl
I see from the tools inspect

```
xsazcd@EPPLGDAW0517:~/app/intellij/idea/current/bin$ ./inspect.sh
No valid license found
2019-11-16 10:29:10,345 [    949]  ERROR -         #GeneralLicenseManager - No valid license found
java.lang.Throwable: No valid license found
        at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:145)
        at com.intellij.ide.b.m.a_.c(a_.java:185)
        at com.intellij.ide.b.m.a_.a(a_.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.start(MainImpl.java:89)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.lambda$prepareAndStart$7(StartupUtil.java:237)
        at com.intellij.util.ui.EdtInvocationManager.executeWithCustomManager(EdtInvocationManager.java:49)
        at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:232)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:42)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.intellij.ide.plugins.MainRunner.lambda$start$0(MainRunner.java:58)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-11-16 10:29:10,353 [    957]  ERROR -         #GeneralLicenseManager - IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4  Build #IU-192.7142.36
2019-11-16 10:29:10,353 [    957]  ERROR -         #GeneralLicenseManager - JDK: 1.8.0_212-release; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: JetBrains s.r.o
2019-11-16 10:29:10,354 [    958]  ERROR -         #GeneralLicenseManager - OS: Linux
xsazcd@EPPLGDAW0517:~/app/intellij/idea/current/bin$ ls ~/app/intellij/
```

I don't have internet connectivity - can I grab the license and place in a folder and make it work?

Comment: Is this helpful? https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544609-How-to-find-the-license-file-or-information-used-by-the-IDE

Comment: To use the tool first you must accept the license agreement and activate the product (either via evaluation license or purchased). After the license information is copied to IDE [config](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519) directory.

Comment: the one in linux does not popup anything - like the one in windows as far I see